# specifying case numbers within do repeat in SPSS

Tags: spss

Apologies if this is a simple question, but how do you perform an operation on a variable within do repeat, but ONLY for particular case numbers? At the minute I have the following unsuccessful code:

```
DO REPEAT x= q12007 to q42007.
DO if $casenum=1.
Compute x = x.
ELSE IF $casenum>1.
Compute x = x-lag(x,1).
end if.
END REPEAT.
execute.
```

Essentially turn the variable into the differenced variable, but without the "do if" everything goes missing. I'm sure there is a simple solution but I haven't found it

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little bit shorter (untested):

```
DO REPEAT x = q12007 to q42007.
+Compute x = x.
+IF ( $casenum > 1 ) x = x - LAG(x).
END REPEAT.
execute.
```

Comment: Removing (the redundant) COMPUTE X=X (as X will already equal X) would make it a line shorter too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your question is and exactly why the code you share doesn't work, further clarification would be very helpful, but you may want to look into the [`CREATE`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_create.htm) command and [`DIFF`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_create_diff_function.htm) function specifically, which calculates lag differences of a specified degree.

Note `CREATE` command doesn't not work within `DO REPEAT` so you would have to wrap it into a native SPSS or Python macro to loop through the variables `q12007 to q42007`.

You mention of running operations on specific case numbers perhaps suggesting needing to run the code iwthin certain subgroups. If so, then also look into [`SPLIT FILE`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_split_file.htm) command.

Comment: Apologies, as to why it doesn't work I'm not certain as no error message appears, it simply doesn't do anything. I have looked at the 'diff' function, but am not familiar with native SPSS or Python macros which was why I was trying to do this with 'DO REPEAT'.

Comment: It's bad practice to overwrite original variables so instead try creating a new set of variables, which may help try follow what's occurring by then investigating the data itself.

Comment: My question then is how I can work that code, but only on cases greater than 1, SPLIT FILE didn't seem the most appropriate. I suppose I could try and create another variable equal to the case number use that to split it, but surely there is a way of referring to case numbers within my bit of code?

Comment: Your use of DO IF with $CASENUM is the correct approach.

Comment: OK, many thanks for your answer, I'll do as you say and create different variables and perhaps that will show why it hasn't worked. And perhaps look up native SPSS macros in the mean time!

Comment: You don't really need to macrofy this. On the face of it it just looks like your creating differencing variables. Which you can achieve with your code as it is (with perhaps some modifications to get it to work). Also, I don't see why you'd equate case 1 to be X and then subsequent cases to be differences. You only need to macrofy if wanting to use the CREATE command. Also, whenever using the LAG function cases usually need to be sorted to a particular order so ensure you are doing this in your work stream.